# Unexpected behavior of alert function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, alert, first-class

I was experimenting on alert but  alert dosen't worked as i expected have look below lines:

```
var tobealerted = function(){return 'worked!'};
```

now when i alert this:

```
alert(tobealerted());
```

this will work fine! now

```
alert(tobealerted);
```

in this i removed parentheses. now it alert `function(){return "worked"}` not `worked!`
now i thought it may be a feature of javascript that it would alert any text without being in quotes then i wrote:

```
alert(worked!)
```

but the google console throw exception `worked!` is undefined , so my thinking was wrong. then again i wrote this

```
alert(function(){})
```

and you know what it alerted `function(){}`! and then i thought that alert would only allow such statement to be alerted without quotes. then again wrote:

```
alert(if(){}) //if is not defined
alert(for(){}) //for is not defined
alert(while(){}) //while is not define
```

but these did not worked for this i searched and found something, from my search i found this

> functions are first class object

and according to wikipedia:

> In computer science, a programming language is said to have
>   first-class functions if it treats functions as first-class citizens.
>   Specifically, this means the language supports passing functions as
>   arguments to other functions, returning them as the values from other
>   functions, and assigning them to variables or storing them in data
>   structures

so my question is

> why did `alert` function only allowed `function (){}` to be alerted but not others

and if you think it is because that function is a first-class object then i don't think so because 
i did not assign this function(last one) to any variable neither it returns anything in `alert(function(){})`

i am so much curious and also confused!
thanks!

Comment: [`message` is an optional string of text you want to display in the alert dialog, **or, alternatively, an object that is converted into a string and displayed**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert)

Comment: *"i thought it may be a feature of javascript that it would alert any text without being in quotes"* By that logic, the output should have been `tobealerted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function is just another type of object in Javascript, so:

```
alert(tobealerted());
```

alerts the function result but:

```
alert(tobealerted);
```

alerts the function object itself using `.toString()` method which returns function's body for objects of type `function`.

Statements like `if` and so on are not objects but full definition of function declares an object. So you can alert function and not `if` statement for example.

Answer (score 5):

You gave the answer yourself. Functions are objects and [as such have `toString()` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Methods). The other examples you gave are `statements`, not `objects`.

As noted by others, [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) only displays `String` objects and triggers the `toString()` function of any other type of object. It expects anything you feed it to be an object or a reference to an object.
This is what happened when you were trying to alert those statements; it assumed `if` etc. were variable names, but it couldn't find any reference by that name.

Answer (score 3):

`alert` converts its argument to a string. That's all.

```
> x = function() { }
function () { }
> x.toString()
"function () { }"
```

You can't invoke `toString()` on an `if`/`for`/`while` as those expressions don't resolve to values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the alert to return a value it must be in quotes like this:

alert('worked!');

If you want it to display a value returned from a function, it must be called as a function:

alert(tobealerted());

Answer (score 0):

If you call a function without the parenthesis, you are basically asking for the definition of the function and because functions are first-class, it will allow you to assign it to a variable.

The if/for/while are conditional operators so they don't work the same as a user-defined function.  They have a very specific use and aren't meant to be overrode.

When you tried `alert(function(){});` it was no different from you trying to assign the function to a variable.  The function definition was stored, but you didn't actually invoke the function.  Now if you did `alert(function(){}());`you would have actually invoked the function and it would have alerted `undefined`.  It is all a matter of defining vs invoking.